# Invertible linear mapping of an open set is still open

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

I am stuck on how to prove an open set is still open after invertible linear transformation.

> If $\delta =(\delta_{1},\dots ,\delta _{d})$ ,$\delta _{i}>0$ for all $i$,and $E \subset \Bbb R^{d}$, we define 
>   $$\delta E= (\delta _{1} x_{1},\dots,\delta _{d} x_{d})$$
>   where$(x_{1}, \dots, x_{d}) \in E$
>
> E is open, prove $\delta E$ is open.

My attempt is that for all $x\in E$, we can find $r$ such that $B_{r}(x)\subset E$. If we define $\delta '$=$\min (\delta _{i})$, then $B_{\delta ' r}(\delta x) \subset \delta E$. But I don't know how to show it formally. Could someone help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean $\delta E = \{ (\delta_1x_1,\dots,\delta_dx_d) :\, (x_1,\dots,x_d)\in E \}$?

Comment: @Azif00 Yes, this is what it means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\colon\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R^n$ is an invertible linear transformation, then $A$ is continuous (for this, being linear is enough). In particular, $A^{-1}$ is continuous. And therefore, if $E\subset\mathbb R^n$, $A(E)=\bigl(A^{-1}\bigr)^{-1}(E)$, which is an open set (it is the inverse image of $E$ with respect to a continuous map).